# Columna en lista de campos ambigua

Tags: mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como lo puedo solucionar, he buscado en internet y no encuentro solución.

Comment: Usa el alias de la tabla: ´SELECT CARRERAS.CARRERA ...´, seguramente hay mas de una columna ´CARRERA´ en tu consulta

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas especificar la tabla que quieres seleccionar asi:

```
SELECT ALUMNOS.CARRERA FROM ALUMNOS INNER JOIN CARRERAS WHERE ALUMNOS.CARRERA=CARRERAS.CARRERA;
```